# Query a specific cell of sqflite data table in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable, sqflite

There are already some questions and answers like "query a specific row". But I want a specific **cell** that means I need a specific row with a specific column from the sqflite data table in Flutter. My table has three columns which are id, fname, fid. But I need only **fid**. Here is my row selection code:

```
queryfid() async {
    Database db = await DatabaseHelper.instance.database;

    List<String> columnsToSelect = [
      DatabaseHelper.columnId,
      DatabaseHelper.columnfname,
      DatabaseHelper.columnfid,
    ];
    String whereString = '${DatabaseHelper.columnId} = ?';
    int rowId = 1;
    List<dynamic> whereArguments = [rowId];
    List<Map> result = await db.query(DatabaseHelper.tableid,
        columns: columnsToSelect,
        where: whereString,
        whereArgs: whereArguments);

    result.forEach((row) => print(row));
  }
```

Comment: Does setting `columnsToSelect` to only `DatabaseHelper.columnfid,` give error ?

Comment: Thanks. You are right. It has worked.